# Angular2 BrowserSync two-way SSL

Tags: node.js, angular, ssl, browser-sync

I'm developing an Angular2 application, and have a request that it should use two-way SSL auth, i.e. the browser must present a valid (PFX) certificate when accessing the application. I'm using lite-server (which uses BrowserSync) for deployment. I studied BrowserSync API and source code, but I'm unable to find any options how to specify this.

I found an example [here](https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2#.jey528oie) which creates a pure node.js server, giving options `requestCert` and `rejectUnauthorized`, but I can't find out how can I use these in BrowserSync. Maybe I should add these somewhere into BrowserSync source?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, this is how I did with a small bash script. There was no proper way to configure Browsersync at the time of writing. By running this script, this modifies the utils.js code in Browsersync by setting some options to support client-side auth.

The script can be run with the `true|false` option specified whether to request or not client-side auth.

```
#!/bin/bash

CLIENT_AUTH=true
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
  CLIENT_AUTH=$1
fi

if [ $CLIENT_AUTH = true ] ; then
  OLD_CLIENT_AUTH=false
else.
  OLD_CLIENT_AUTH=true
fi

FILE=./node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/utils.js
REPLACE="requestCert:$CLIENT_AUTH,rejectUnauthorized:$CLIENT_AUTH,"
FROM="requestCert:$OLD_CLIENT_AUTH,rejectUnauthorized:$OLD_CLIENT_AUTH,"

grep requestCert $FILE >/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
  sed -i "s/ca: getCa(options),/ca: getCa(options),$REPLACE/g" $FILE
else
  sed -i "s/$FROM/$REPLACE/g" $FILE
fi
```